# Finding every combination of different length lists in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, permutation, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All possible permutations of a set of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853212/all-possible-permutations-of-a-set-of-lists-in-python)

I want to find every combination of different length character lists in Python. For example, I have the following lists which define possible characters in a string:

```
list1=['a','d','e','f','b']
list2=['h','s','c','v','e', 'u', '?', "^", "k"]
list3=['a','d]
list4=[',','4','u','t','R','x', ' ']
list5=['%','e','u','y']
```

And I want to find every combination of the lists in to the string, i.e. "aha,%", "dha,%", "eha,%".

One could simply use varied nested loops, but with many more lists this is not practical.

This seems like it should be a simple problem.

Comment: Duplicate of lots of questions, I chose one almost at random.  Short version: use `itertools.product` to get all the possibilities, and then `''.join` to reconstruct the string.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to have a list of lists, instead of that many individual lists.