# All possible permutations of multiple lists and sizes

Tags: python, list, permutation

It's easy in python to calculate simple permutations using [itertools.permutations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

You can even find some [possible permutations of multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2853212).

```
import itertools
s=[ [ 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f'] ]
for l in list(itertools.product(*s)):
    print(l)


('a', 'd', 'e')
('a', 'd', 'f')
('b', 'd', 'e')
('b', 'd', 'f')
('c', 'd', 'e')
('c', 'd', 'f')
```

It's also possible to find [permutations of different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/99923).

```
import itertools
s = [1, 2, 3]
for L in range(0, len(s)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(s, L):
        print(subset)

()
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

How would you find permutations of all possible 1) **lengths**, 2) **orders**, and 3) from **multiple lists**?

I would assume the first step would be to combine the lists into one. A list will not de-dup items like a set would.

```
s=[ [ 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f'] ]

('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('a', 'e')
('a', 'f')
...
('b', 'a')
('c', 'a')
...
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
...
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
...
('f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
```

Comment: if you flatten the list, doesn't it solve it?

Comment: @BcK this most certainly is not a duplicate of questions about flattening lists. If anything, this would be a duplicate of the two questions I already linked to about finding permutations. However, I already explained the differences in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you suggested, do:

```
s = [x for y in s for x in y]
```

and then use your solution for finding permutations of different lengths:

```
for L in range(0, len(s)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(s, L):
        print(subset)
```

would find:

```
()
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
('d',)
('e',)
('f',)
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('a', 'e')
('a', 'f')
('b', 'c')
('b', 'd')
('b', 'e')
('b', 'f')
('c', 'd')
('c', 'e')
('c', 'f')
('d', 'e')
('d', 'f')
('e', 'f')
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'f')
('a', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'c', 'e')
('a', 'c', 'f')
('a', 'd', 'e')
('a', 'd', 'f')
('a', 'e', 'f')
('b', 'c', 'd')
('b', 'c', 'e')
('b', 'c', 'f')
('b', 'd', 'e')
('b', 'd', 'f')
('b', 'e', 'f')
('c', 'd', 'e')
('c', 'd', 'f')
('c', 'e', 'f')
('d', 'e', 'f')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'f')
('a', 'b', 'd', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'd', 'f')
('a', 'b', 'e', 'f')
('a', 'c', 'd', 'e')
('a', 'c', 'd', 'f')
('a', 'c', 'e', 'f')
('a', 'd', 'e', 'f')
('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
('b', 'c', 'd', 'f')
('b', 'c', 'e', 'f')
('b', 'd', 'e', 'f')
('c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f')
('a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f')
('a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
```

If you want to distinguish e.g. `('d', 'e', 'f')` from `('f', 'e', 'd')` (thanks [@Kefeng91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9729313/kefeng91) for pointing this out) and others, replace `itertools.combinations` with `itertools.permutations`, like [@YakymPirozhenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4585963/yakym-pirozhenko) suggests.

Comment: Good solution so far, but it fails to handle different orders.

Comment: Do you have an (counter)example of that?

Comment: @fferri I think this will work if you replace `combinations` with `permutations`, which is what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple one liner (You can replace `feature_cols` instead of `s`)

**Combinations:**

```py
[combo for i in range(1, len(feature_cols) + 1) for combo in itertools.combinations(feature_cols, i) ]
```

**Permutations:**

```py
[combo for i in range(1, len(feature_cols) + 1) for combo in itertools.permutations(feature_cols, i) ]
```

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694374/8751871) for more details