# How do I get combinations of a list of words in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that if I gave it a list of words such as ('1', '2', '3') it would give me:

1
12
13
123
232
2
21
23
213
231
3
31
32
31
32
312
321

I have tried itertools but I couldn't figure it out
How can I do this?

Thankyou

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242147/all-possible-permutations-of-multiple-lists-and-sizes

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations sounds useful for your need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Comment: Is 232 a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a variant of the [powerset recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) using permutations instead of combinations:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

def powerperm(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(permutations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))

inp = ('1', '2', '3')

out = list(map(''.join, powerperm(inp)))
out
```

output: `['1', '2', '3', '12', '13', '21', '23', '31', '32', '123', '132', '213', '231', '312', '321']`