# Permutations in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, permutation

I have a list containing `n` integers. The `i`th element of the list `a`, `a[i]`, can be swapped into any integer `x` such that `0 ≤ x ≤ a[i]`. For example if `a[i]` is 3, it can take values `0, 1, 2, 3`.

The task is to find all permutations of such list. For example, if the list is

```
my_list = [2,1,4]
```

then the possible permutations are:

```py
[0,0,0], [0,0,1], ... [0,0,4],
[0,1,0], [0,1,1], ... [0,1,4],
[1,0,0], [1,0,1], ... [1,0,4],
[1,1,0], [1,1,1], ... [1,1,4],
[2,0,0], [2,0,1], ... [2,0,4],
[2,1,0], [2,1,1], ... [2,1,4]
```

How to find all such permutations?

Comment: Your wording is not clear here.  In your example, would `[2,2,4]` be a valid permutation (having replaced the second element with 2)? Your second sentence indicates yes but I predict that is not an exactly true statement.  What you have said is you can replace the 1st element with 0 or 1, the 2nd with 0,1 or 2, the third by 0,1,2 or 3.  I imagine you want each element to be able to be replaced with an integer lower than its VALUE (not index), but that is not what your question says.

Comment: @Hoog Yes you got it right, that is what I want. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

you could use a comibation of `range` to get all the 'valid' values for each element of the list and `itertools.product`:

```py
import itertools

my_list = [2,1,4]

# get a list of lists with all the possible values
plist = [list(range(y+1)) for y in my_list]

#
permutations = sorted(list(itertools.product(*plist)))
```

more on itertools product see e.g. [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853212/all-possible-permutations-of-a-set-of-lists-in-python) or [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Let me know if I misunderstood your question

```
def permute(l,cnt,n):
    if cnt==n:
        print(l)
        return 
    limit = l[cnt]
    for i in range(limit+1):
        l[cnt]=i
        permute(l[:n],cnt+1,n)
    
l =[2,1,4]
permute(l,0,3)
```

Comment: nice recursive solution! although it takes some more iterations than there are premutations. some comments on how this works and how to use it would be nice.

Comment: This is a kind of brute force solution. We know that finally, we will have an array of size n and at each index the value can be varied in a range say x to y  where x is 1 and y is the_given_array[index] so you can view the recursion call to be doing something like putting 0 at 0 then 0 at 1.... printing 00000 followed by 00001... I hope this helps. Let me know if you need more explanation and ideally it should take iterations only the required number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
my_list=[2,1,4]    
def premutation_list(p_list):
    the_number=int("".join(map(str,p_list)))
    total_len=len(str(the_number))
    a=[i for i in range(the_number)]
    r_list=[]
    for i in a:
        if len(str(i))<total_len:
            add_rate=total_len - len(str(i))
            b="0,"*add_rate
            b=b.split(",")
            b=b[0:len(b)-1]
            b.append(str(i))
            r_list.append([int(y) for x in b for y in x ])
        else:
            r_list.append([int(x) for x in str(i)])

    return r_list
print(premutation_list(my_list))
```

Explanation:

- The basic idea is just getting all the numbers till the given number. For example till 4 there are `0,1,2,3,` number.
- I have achieved this first by converting the list into a integer.
- Then getting all the numbers till `the_number`.